# My program is not correctly reading lines from a file sequentially

Tags: python, text-files, raw-input

This is an assignment from Python For Everyone Chapter 10 assignment 10.2 in which the problem states

> Write a program to read through the mbox-short.txt and figure out the distribution by hour of the day for each of the messages. You can pull the hour out from the 'From ' line by finding the time and then splitting the string a second time using a colon.
>   "From person@example.com Sat Jan  5 09:14:16 2008"
>   Once you have accumulated the counts for each hour, print out the counts, sorted by hour as shown below.

The desired output is

```
04 3
06 1
07 1
09 2
10 3
11 6
14 1
15 2
16 4
17 2
18 1
19 1
```

my code is here

```
`name = raw_input("Enter file:")
if len(name) < 1 : name = "mbox-short.txt"
handle = open(name)
counts = dict()

for line in handle:
    line = line.rstrip()
    if line.startswith("From "):
        parts = line.split()
#        print parts
        time = parts[5]
        pieces = time.split(':')
        hour = pieces[0]
        counts[hour] = counts.get(hour,0)+1
print counts `
```

The text file can be found here http://www.pythonlearn.com/code/mbox-short.txt
When debugging, I realized that my compiler goes through each line many times to return values for each hour that is way too high. I'm sure that the syntax `line.startswith("From ")` is correct for only reading the intended lines because I used in a previous assignment.

How can I get the correct frequency for hours?

Comment: It would help if you showed your actual output.

Comment: It's a mixed tabs and spaces problem. Python doesn't see your indentation the same way you do. Turn on "show whitespace" in your editor to see the problem; your editor may also have a "convert tabs to spaces" feature to fix it. Running Python with the `-tt` flag can help catch these errors.

Comment: Thank you it seemed to be an indentation error. Turning on that option in my editor is a really helpful change for writing code. Thanks!

Comment: Minor hint as you grow in python: read up on collections; collections.defaultdict is my goto, but I think there's also one specifically designed for your use case (Counter?) ... specifically, you can do counts[hour] += 1 and not worry about if counts has hour as a key, if counts is e.g. defaultdict(int)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you code works fine as I tried it.

for the output a dictionary is unsorted.
you can use sort(counts) which returns a sorted list of the keys. with these you can print your dict in a sorted way

```
name = raw_input("Enter file:")
if len(name) < 1 : name = "mbox-short.txt"
handle = open(name)
counts = dict()

for line in handle:
    line = line.rstrip()
    if line.startswith("From "):
        parts = line.split()
        time = parts[5]
        pieces = time.split(':')
        hour = pieces[0]
        counts[hour] = counts.get(hour,0)+1

for key in sorted(counts):
    print key + " " + str(counts[key])
```

output is

```
04 3
06 1
07 1
09 2
10 3
11 6
14 1
15 2
16 4
17 2
18 1
19 1
```